# Simulate capacitor discharge in Qucs

Tags: capacitor, simulation, qucs

I want to find how long a capacitor takes to discharge from 12 volts to 2 volts using Qucs. I can use a voltmeter to measure the voltage across it when it charges up, but I cannot turn the power source off during simulation.

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Qucs, but there ought to be a way to add a time- or voltage-controlled switch to your simulation, which can disconnect the capacitor from the power source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the really cool lumped components in Qucs is a **time controlled switch**.
You can specify the initial value as open or closed (see below), as well as a list of times when the switch should change state. [Example of how it's used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h40s.jpg)

[image: Qucs time controlled switch]

Actually, the time-controlled switch is really a time-controlled two-state resistor with default values [R<sub>on</sub>=0 Ω; R<sub>off</sub>=1e12 Ω].

You can choose **any** value for R<sub>on</sub> and R<sub>off</sub>. Combined with the list of times when the state changes, [this a powerful and easy-to-use](https://github.com/Qucs/qucs/wiki/Time-Domain-Simulation)  time-controlled element in simulations.